# Replacing values in a row based on conditions

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to fill down a column based on 2 conditions. In this case, whether the index (time series) falls between sunrise and sunset, in which case I want 1 in a new column called "sunlight'. Otherwise, I want the value to be zero. I'm new to pandas from excel so I'm trying to do this as I would there, probably wrongly.

```
df['sunlight'] = 0
mask1 = df.index > df['sunrise']
mask2 = df.index < df['sunset']
df[mask1 & mask2]
df.loc[df[mask1 & mask2],'sunlight'] = 1
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCDjd.jpg)

| Index | sunrise | sunset | Sunlight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08:18:00 | 08:19:17 | 15:56:43 | 0 |
| 08:19:00 | 08:19:17 | 15:56:43 | 0 |
| 08:20:00 | 08:19:17 | 15:56:43 | 1 |
| 08:21:00 | 08:19:17 | 15:56:43 | 1 |
| 08:22:00 | 08:19:17 | 15:56:43 | 1 |

Comment: It would be nice if you can share input and expected output.

Comment: The output would be a column with either 1 where the index time fell between sunrise and sunset, or zero. Does that help? There's also an image which I hope explains what I'm trying to do.

Comment: may you try `df['index']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let`s look on a DataFrame with only on day of data with a frequency of one hour (not minutes) as an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sunrais':[pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 08:19:17')]*24, 
                   'sunset':[pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 15:46:43')]*24 }, 
                   index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 23:00:00', freq='H')
                 )
```

If you now cast the truth value as integer you can multiply both selections in one step.

```
df['sunlight'] = (df['sunrais']<df.index).astype(int) * (df.index<df['sunset']).astype(int)
```

The the output looks like this:

```
                                sunrais              sunset  sunlight
2020-01-01 07:00:00 2020-01-01 08:19:17 2020-01-01 15:46:43         0
2020-01-01 08:00:00 2020-01-01 08:19:17 2020-01-01 15:46:43         0
2020-01-01 09:00:00 2020-01-01 08:19:17 2020-01-01 15:46:43         1
2020-01-01 10:00:00 2020-01-01 08:19:17 2020-01-01 15:46:43         1
```